# Simplest way to add DOCTYPE to Scala XML?

Tags: xml, html, scala

How can I make this miminal HTML5 in Scala XML:
`<!DOCTYPE html><title></title><p></p></html>`?

Of course it's simple to make an HTML-like XML in Scala:

```
> val html = <html><title></title><p></p></html>
html: scala.xml.Elem = <html><title></title><p></p></html>
```

However, how can I inject a `DOCTYPE` attribute prefixed in the `html` tag?

Two routes I tried:
Using the `scala.xml.Document` and `scala.xml.DocType`, but both seemed predicated on writing out a file or stream, whereas I'm just keeping this XML object in memory. Seemed like too much ceremony.

Using [Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600997/construct-xml-with-dynamic-label-and-attributes-in-scala/1601677#1601677),

```
> import scala.xml.{Null, Text, Attribute}
> val d = <html /> % Attribute(None, "!DOCTYPE", Text(""), Null)
d: scala.xml.Elem = <html !DOCTYPE=""></html>
```

which is close, but not a prefixed attribute and with a naughty assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use XML's write method that takes a java.io.Writer instead of a File. Using java.io.StringWriter is straight forward:

```
val w = new java.io.StringWriter()
val html = <html><body><p>Que pasa?!</p></body></html>
xml.XML.write(w, html, "UTF-8", xmlDecl = false, doctype = 
   xml.dtd.DocType("html", xml.dtd.SystemID("about:legacy-compat"), Nil))
w.toString
```

Comment: Was hoping for a less involved way, but four lines isn't much for doing what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the doctype tag to scala xml structures, but you can inject it when you are turning it into a string.