# Scala and xml metadata

Tags: xml, scala

I have xml as a string which I load into Elem so I can use Scala's xml functions to it and then I convert that Elem back to a string. During this process xml's metadata (doctype and xml declaration) is lost. How should I preserve it?

I have found that I can use XML.write with StringWriter to convert Node to string with metadata ([Simplest way to add DOCTYPE to Scala XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491067/simplest-way-to-add-doctype-to-scala-xml)). Is there an easy way to load metadata from xml string or how should I do it?