# Scala XML varargs attributes

Tags: xml, scala, variadic-functions

Ran across this [ancient thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600997/construct-xml-with-dynamic-label-and-attributes-in-scala) on applying varargs to an XML node, but no definitive answer for this particular problem came of it (accepted answer answers everything *but* this issue).

Have a pretty gruesome hack in place to avoid resorting to XML.loadString("...") for generating XHTML form fields.

```
def nodeCopy(e: Elem, args: (Symbol,Any)*): Elem = {

  val a = args.map{case(s,v)=> Attribute(None,s.name,Text(v.toString),Null) }
  a.size match{
    case 0 => e
    case 1 => e % a(0)
    case 2 => e % a(0) % a(1) 
    case 3 => e % a(0) % a(1) % a(2)
    case 4 => e % a(0) % a(1) % a(2) % a(3)
    case 5 => e % a(0) % a(1) % a(2) % a(3) % a(4)
    case 6 => e % a(0) % a(1) % a(2) % a(3) % a(4) % a(5)
    case _ => e % a(0) % a(1) % a(2) % a(3) % a(4) % a(5) % a(6)
  }
}

// usage (where args could be: ('id, "foo"), ('class, "bar"), ...)
nodeCopy(<input name={k} value={v} />, args:_*)
```

Is there a better approach to generating dynamic XML Elems with Scala 2.10??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very literal translation into a fold:

```
def nodeCopy(e: Elem, args: (Symbol, Any)*): Elem = args.foldLeft(e) {
  case (currentElem, (s, v)) =>
    currentElem % Attribute(None, s.name, Text(v.toString), Null)
}
```

This works the same as your implementation, but for arbitrarily many attributes.

Comment: Nice, Travis, that's quite a bit more palatable ;-)

Comment: p.s. might as well add your answer to the referenced question as that comes up frequently in search engine results for topic at hand